# Access to undeclared static property: mysqli::$insert_id

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using core php for my current project and to get last insert id I am using `mysqli::$insert_id` but facing the following error.

> Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: mysqli::$insert_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\library\libdb.php on line 123

Following is my code to get the last `insret_id`:

```
if(mysqli_query($con,$query))
         return mysqli::$insert_id;
     else
         return false;
```

Comment: It's a property of the class, but it's not a static property. You need to access it as `$con->insert_id;`, not `mysqli::$insert_id`.

Comment: Thanks its working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for last insert id use

```
$con->insert_id;
```